# Generar botones automaticamnete en Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-layout

Quiero generar tantos botones como hijos tenga en Firebase, por ahora tengo esto:

```
 myRef.child("Oportunidad").child(user.getUid()).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
            ListaIDOportunidad.add(dataSnapshot.getKey());

            for(int i=0;i<ListaIDOportunidad.size();i++) {
                modulosActivos.setModulo(ListaIDOportunidad.get(i));
                if (ListaIDOportunidad.get(i).equals(modulosActivos.getModulo())){
                    System.out.println("Modulo " + i);

                }
                button.setText(modulosActivos.getModulo());
                button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

        }
```

Que lop que hace es cambiar el texto del boton y hacerlo visible, y en el .xml  tengo una serie de botones y lo unico que hago es eso hacerlo visible, me gustaria generar el boton de alguna forma cuando haigan hijos, es decir leo los hijos los almaceno en el ArrayList y luego al leer el Array quiero que dependiendo de el numero de array que exista se generen un boton por cada uno pero no veo como hacerlo.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
>
    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <Button
                android:text="Button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/button" android:layout_weight="1"
                android:visibility="invisible"/>
        <Button
                android:text="Button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/button2" android:layout_weight="1"
                android:visibility="invisible"/>
        <Button
                android:text="Button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/button3" android:layout_weight="1"
                android:visibility="invisible"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Con el siguiente codigo podras gennerar una array de botones. Puedes traer de firebase tus json para mappear a objetos y con un for each crear los botones.

```
    //Obtiene instancia de contenedor padre
LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
//Definimos un texto en base al cual se crearan los botones.
String s = "TEXTOEJEMPLO";
String[] letras = s.split("");;//Convierte texto a arreglo Char

int cantidadBotones = s.length(); //Obtenemos la cantidad de  botones a dibujar.
for (int i = 0; i < cantidadBotones; i++) {
    Button bn = new Button(getApplicationContext());
    bn.setId(1 + 2000); //Define ids
    bn.setMinHeight(0);
    bn.setMinimumHeight(0);
    bn.setPadding(0,0,0,0); //Elimina padding
    bn.setTextSize(14);
    bn.setText(letras[i+1]); //Asigna letra.
    //Crea contenedor con peso de 1 para cada elemento.
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f);
    bn.setLayoutParams(params);
    //Agrega vista a contenedor padre.
    container.addView(bn);
}
```